# Bootstrap tooltip data-toggle

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In the Bootstrap documentation page, the tooltip has a signature of:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>
```

What does the "data-toggle" attribute do in this scenario?

I know it's useful for tabs but I don't see what usefulness it can bring to tooltips.

---

Chris,

The tooltip has to be initialized explicitly as in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".link").tooltip();
});
```

Assuming that the "a" tag has a class of "link". The "data-toggle" attribute is not mandatory for the tooltip to function correctly. But you mentioned that it is for the Bootstrap JavaScript file to recognize if something is a tooltip. So it doesn't seem to make sense that omitting "data-toggle" still makes the tooltip work (as long as there is the explicit initialization). Could you explain further?

Edit #2:

After reading some GitHub issue pages, I think I have come to the following conclusion (which is my best guess).

Originally, in older versions of Bootstrap, the tooltip signature was:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>
...
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me again!</a>
```

And developers could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

To activate *all* tooltips at once (since each tooltip requires an initialization to work). In other words, it was just a convenient way to identity all the tooltips so that you can use jQuery to activate all of them.

But rel="tooltip" did not validate against HTML5, so folks started suggesting using data-toggle="tooltip" because Bootstrap already uses data-toggle for other components and data-* is valid in HTML5.

Thus, my guess is that there is no special semantic meaning or purpose for data-toggle="tooltip" other than to provide a convenient way to identity all tooltips.

Note that you could also identity the tooltips using ID or class, but why not activate all tooltips at once (rhetorical question)?

Comment: platypus, if you have come up with an answer to your own question, kindly add it as a new Answer (form at the bottom of the page) rather than adding it to the question itself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading some GitHub issue pages, I think I have come to the following conclusion (which is my best guess).

Originally, in older versions of Bootstrap, the tooltip signature was:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>
...
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me again!</a>
```

And developers could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

To activate all tooltips at once (since each tooltip requires an initialization to work). In other words, it was just a convenient way to identify all the tooltips so that you can use jQuery to activate all of them.

But rel="tooltip" did not validate against HTML5, so folks started suggesting using data-toggle="tooltip" because Bootstrap already uses data-toggle for other components and data-* is valid in HTML5.

Thus, my guess is that there is no special semantic meaning or purpose for data-toggle="tooltip" other than to provide a convenient way to identity all tooltips.

Note that you could also identify the tooltips using ID or class, but why not activate all tooltips at once (rhetorical question)?

Answer (score 6):

i use this:

```
<script>
    $('[title]').tooltip();
</script>
```

it selects all elements where is attribute title defined, and replaces default tooltip behavior with the bootstrapped one..

Answer (score 1):

They've chosen to use `data-toggle` as an indicator in their JavaScript for when something is a tooltip. When the tooltips JS file sees the `data-toggle="tooltip"` attribute, it knows to kick in and run.

A more common approach might be to use a class (`<a href="#" class="tooltip" title="first tooltip">hover over me</a>`), but they've gone `data-*` attribute instead. Does the same thing, works, and philisophically, `data-*` attributes were designed for JavaScript manipulation, so I suppose it's good to keep it class free.

Comment: You know, in looking through the script on GitHub, I'm at a loss. I don't see it referenced anywhere in the code. So yea...