# Bootstrap tooltip with x-editable plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying  to make work tooltip and x-editable plugin together

this is my anchor print code

```
  <?php $Cvstate.="<a href=\"#\" id=\"cvstage\" style=\" text-decoration:none;\"  data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-container=\"body\" data-placement=\"top\" data-original-title=\"{$row['idate']}\">Cv Send</a><br><br>" ;?>
```

and when add x-editable plugin attributes looks like this

```
  <?php $Cvstate .= "<a href=\"#vacancy\" id=\"cvstage\" style=\"margin: 15px; text-decoration:none;\" data-type=\"select\" data-pk=\"1\"  data-source=\"/groups\" data-value=\"{$row['id']}\" data-title=\"Select group\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" data-container=\"body\" data-placement=\"top\" data-original-title=\"{$t['date']}\">Cv Send</a> <br>"; ?>
```

The problem is when i add `data-toggle="tooltip"` to it x-editable plugin is not working and when i remove it x-editable plugin works but tooltip is not workings. Any idea from where this bug coming?

**[Link to plugin](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html)**

Answer (score 3):

I also had a conflict between x-editable and bootstrap tooltip. After reading through the information at [Bootstrap tooltip data-toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17255367/bootstrap-tooltip-data-toggle), I decided to try the following selector for tooltips instead.

```
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-title]'});
});
```

This works well with the x-editable plugin since you can specify a *data-title* as one of the options. E.g.

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```

You just need to ensure that you update all the references to your previous tooltip selector.

This will enable you to use x-editable and bootstrap tooltip on the same element.

Comment: there's an excess closing brace and closing parenthesis on the jquery code

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fixed code.

JS

```
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-title]'
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="username" data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-title="Enter username">superuser</a>
```